# How to add ASCII only data annotation

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I am using data annotations for validation and I want to use a RegularExpression Data annotation to check the string has only ASCII characters.

```
      public class SomeObject
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(4000)]       
    [RegularExpression(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Can you help me fix the regular expression to allow only ASCII characters

Comment: im sure that is nothing like how you can do it. ASCII characters would basically be every key on your keyboard plus more.. so i would image this looks to simple to be valid. Im going to follow this, ps what did google say.

Comment: @dlatikay you beet me by like 3 secs im sure

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test for the full ASCII set:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[\x00-\x7F]+$")]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

And if not for the full ASCII set (this **won't** pass for characters other than **a-z** (uppercase too) and **0-9**):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\w+$")]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yea, you're right. Since both upper and lowercase should pass the test, **\w** seems a better choice.